# Genetic Algorithm for Appliance Scheduling in java

Tags: java, arrays, csv, binary, genetic-algorithm

i am doing a project on household appliance scheduling using genetic algorithm in java.  I have little knowledge of genetic algorithm and Java programming.  I would really appreciate if anyone could help me.

My project is to schedule appliances like washing machine, aircon etc. in a 48 time slot with varying electricity price for each slot but it stays constant in one slot. My objective is to have minimum cost. Using binary to represent the appliance ON/OFF. Solution should be in n x m matrix

For washing machine for example, it has a cycle of 1 hour, thus the binary should look like this "0000110000..." and not " 0001010000" and also there is preferred ON period for appliances for example 6-8am and 6-10pm and if the appliance is to be used 2x a day then it will be 1x during the 6-8am slot and 1x during the 6-10pm.

Also i have to include renewable source(PV) to sell when the price is right or store the energy to supply when it is not worth to sell. I'm not sure how. Should this be another GA? Or can it be together?

How do i start to program this? And how do i use excel file to store info about appliance so that i can extract it from excel when i need.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

first I suggest develop the model for the genetic algo, i didn't understand exactly how the model is going to work

you need to define those key components:

- how to represent the problem with chromosomes (building blocks)
- how to induce mutation and breed between 2 (or more) chromosomes
- fit function to evaluate each solution

I suggest because of your lack of knowledge in java, start with a coding lang you familiar with, best approach will be an oriented data lang like Python or R, if you don't familiar with any I suggest go with Python

once you develop and tested your model (the hard part) you can write it in java if you want to... (my suggestion is to use python all the way)

I suggest focus on that first, all other utilities like excel csv and such are pretty straight forward once you have your model and data figured out and implemented

the good news you are using the best approach to solve this NP problem, I suggest to search in the internet for implementation of this problem's variants

also take a look at this solution to the [traveling salesman problem](http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/applying-a-genetic-algorithm-to-the-travelling-salesman-problem/5) to get familiar with the genetic algo approach